# not able to display frame when i click on jbutton image

Tags: java, swing, jframe, applet, jbutton

```
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;
  import java.applet.*;
  import javax.swing.*;
  /*<applet code="Olyproex" height=650 width=1450></applet>*/

  //button create in gridbaglayout
  public class Olyproex extends Applet
    {
       Font f1; 
       GridBagLayout g1; 
       GridBagConstraints gbc;
       JButton b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7;
       JFrame fm1;
       Image pic;
      //button creation code
       public void  init()    
            {  
                b1=new JButton();
                b1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\javaproject\\img.jpg"));
                b2=new JButton(new ImageIcon("E:\\javaproject\\img.jpg"));
                b3=new JButton(new ImageIcon("E:\\javaproject\\img.jpg"));
                b4=new JButton(new ImageIcon("E:\\javaproject\\img.jpg"));
                b5=new JButton(new ImageIcon("E:\\javaproject\\img.jpg"));
                b6=new JButton(new ImageIcon("E:\\javaproject\\img.jpg"));
                b7=new JButton(new ImageIcon("E:\\javaproject\\img.jpg"));
                f1 = new Font("Arial Black",Font.BOLD,36); 
                pic = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"img.jpg");
                g1 = new GridBagLayout();
                gbc= new GridBagConstraints();
                setLayout(g1);
                gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                gbc.gridx=0;
                gbc.gridy=0;
                gbc.gridwidth=2;
                gbc.ipady=40;
                gbc.ipadx=40;
                add(b1,gbc);
                gbc.gridx=4;
                gbc.gridy=0;
                gbc.ipady=40;
                gbc.ipadx=40;
                add(b2,gbc);
                gbc.gridx=8;
                gbc.gridy=0;
                gbc.ipady=40;
                gbc.ipadx=40;
                add(b3,gbc);
                gbc.gridx=0;
                gbc.gridy=4;
                gbc.ipady=40;
                gbc.ipadx=40;
                add(b4,gbc);
                gbc.gridx=4;
                gbc.gridy=4;
                gbc.ipady=40;
                gbc.ipadx=40;
                add(b5,gbc);
                gbc.gridx=8;
                gbc.gridy=4;
                gbc.ipady=40;
                gbc.ipadx=40;
                add(b6,gbc);
                gbc.gridx=4;
                gbc.gridy=8;
                gbc.ipady=40;
                gbc.ipadx=40;
                add(b7,gbc);   
                b1.setActionCommand("b1");           
      }
                //onclick button code
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("b1"))
                             {
                                fm1 = new JFrame("Second"); 
                                fm1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                                fm1.setSize(300,300);
                                fm1.setVisible(true);
                              }
                    }
           }
```

Comment: please give solution

Comment: shouldn;t you extend your class from JApplet rather than Applet

Comment: Also do you know applets are no longer part of JDK , they had been removed in JDK11, and had been deprecated since JDK9

Comment: but i have jdk 8 version

Comment: ok then try the change that I suggested for Applet to JApplet and see if it works

Comment: @Satya *"try the change that I suggested for Applet to JApplet"* There is only one problem I can think of that would be caused by using `Applet` rather than `JApplet`, & it's not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

That code, as well as the debugging of it, has many problems. The one causing the current conundrum is:

```
fm1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Applets work in a security sandbox. It has varying level of permissions, none of which will allow an applet (or a frame launched by it) to end the JVM. There would be errors shown in the Java Console. Check it for all applet problems.

To fix it, instead use:

```
fm1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```